# How to concatenate API request URL safely

Tags: url, kotlin, concatenation

Let's imagine I have the following parts of a URL:

```
val url_start = "http://example.com"
val url_part_1 = "&fields[...]&" //This part of url can be in the middle of url or in the end
val url_part_2 = "&include..."
```

And then I try to concatenate the resulting URL like this:

```
val complete_url = url_start + url_part_2 + url_part_1
```

In this case I'd get `http://example.com&include...&fields[...]&` (don't consider syntax here), which is one `&` symbol between URL parts which means that concatenation was successful, **BUT** if I use different concat sequence in a different request like this:

```
val complete_url = url_start + url_part_1 + url_part_2
```

I'd get `http://example.com&fields[...]&&include...`, to be specific `&&` in this case. Is there a way to ensure that concatenation is *safer*?

Comment: Don't  do that. Store a collection and join them when the request is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep you code clean use an array or object to keep your params and doin't keep "?" or "&" as part of urlStart or params. Add these at the end. e.g.

```
var urlStart = "http://example.com"
var params=[]
params.push ('a=1')
params.push ('b=2')
params.push ('c=3', 'd=4')
url = urlStart + '?' + params.join('&')
console.log (url)  // http://example.com?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should note that it is invalid to have query parameters just after domain name; it should be something like `http://example.com/?include...&fields[...]` (note the `/?` part, you can replace it with `/` to make it a path parameter, but it's not likely that the router of the website supports parameters like this). Refer, for example, to this article: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/ to know more about what URLs can be valid.

For the simple abstract approach, you can use Kotlin's [`joinToString()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html):

```
val query_part = arrayOf(
    "fields[...]",
    "include..."
).joinToString("&")
val whole_url = "http://example.com/?" + query_part
print(whole_url) // http://example.com/?fields[...]&include...
```

This approach is abstract because you can use `joinToString()` not only for URLs, but for whatever strings you want. This also means that if there will be an `&` symbol in one of the input strings itself, it will become two parameters in the output string. This is not a problem when you, as a programmer, know what strings will be joined, but if these strings are provided by user, it can become a problem.

For URL-aware approach, you can use [`URIBuilder`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) from [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) library, but you'll need to import this library first.